# How to use SelectInput() to select column names instead of by row values

Tags: r, shiny, reactive, selectinput

I am trying to build an RShiny app that displays 2 dropdown menus in the UI, where the first dropdown menu selects the species, and the second dropdown menu selects a data that is available for that species.

I looked at [this post](https://sites.temple.edu/psmgis/2017/07/26/r-shiny-task-create-an-input-select-box-that-is-dependent-on-a-previous-input-choice/) for a possible way to do this, but this seems best for data where the options to include in the dropdown menu are rows of a data frame, not columns. I also realize this example created their own data table from scratch, but I want to use my data frame because I want to keep the data associated with it.

The data I am currently working with looks more like this format:

```
Haddock_age1length <- c("33", "34", "32")
Haddock_weight <- c("14", "16", "15")
squid_width <- c("30", "32", "34")
squid_weight <- c("10", "11", "15")
Year <- c("2000", "2001", "2002")

df <- data.frame(Haddock_age1length, Haddock_weight,squid_width, squid_weight,Year)
    
Haddock_age1length     Haddock_weight     squid_width     squid_weight     Year
    33                      14                 30              10          2000
    34                      16                 32              11          2001
    32                      15                 34              15          2002
```

my question is, how can I use the `selectInput()` function to create one dropdown menu to select species such as "Haddock" or "Squid", and then another one that lists the corresponding data available for each species?

e.g: the options under "Haddock" would be "Age 1 Length" and "Weight", where the options under "Squid" would be "Width" and "Weight", so that if someone selected "Haddock" and "Weight", the "Haddock_weight" column of the data frame would be called.

If possible, I would like to not reformat the dataframe as after selection, as I hope to render a plotly timeseries lineplot for the data selected.

Thanks!

Comment: I think it would make sense for you to use a [tidy data set](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html), i.e. transform it to the long format. Then you would have columns that you can use for the `selectInput`s (e.g. species and measurement).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this is what you are looking for? Two different `selectInput`, first you select the species, then the second is any of the columns that include the species name:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

Haddock_age1length <- c("33", "34", "32")
Haddock_weight <- c("14", "16", "15")
squid_width <- c("30", "32", "34")
squid_weight <- c("10", "11", "15")
Year <- c("2000", "2001", "2002")

df <- data.frame(Haddock_age1length, Haddock_weight,squid_width, squid_weight,Year)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("Species", "Species", choices = c("Haddock", "Squid")),
  uiOutput("ColumnUI"),

  tableOutput("TABLE")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$ColumnUI<-renderUI({
    selectInput("COLUMN", "Column?", choices = names(df%>%select(grep(input$Species, names(.), ignore.case = T))))
  })
  
  output$TABLE<-renderTable({
    req(input$COLUMN)
    df[input$COLUMN]
    
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```